# PHP: image upload

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload an image with this script. Bit it keeps giving me this error: The file you attempted to upload is not allowed. And the files that i tried to upload where jpg and png.

Can someone tell whats going wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'images/tekeningen/';
description = $_POST['imgdesc'];

$filename = $_FILES['userfile'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
$query = "INSERT INTO uploads (description) VALUES ($filename, $description)"; 
mysql_query($query);

echo 'Your file upload was successful!';


} else {
echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
}
}
```

Comment: var_dump($ext); and you will find it out .

Comment: Your script will fail when there are `.` in your filename, you should get the extension like this : `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not properly get your extension. Your script is not going to work when the filename contains `.`.

To get the file extension, I would recommend this

```
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

and removing the `.` in your allowed extensions like so :

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

instead of

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile'];
```

---

this

```
filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])
```

instead of

```
filesize($_FILES['userfile'])
```

---

this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
```

instead of this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile'],$upload_path . $filename))
```

### [Refer this tutorial](http://www.tutorialscollection.com/php-file-upload-how-to-upload-file-in-php-using-_files-in-script-of-php/)

### For security reason

You should not use check only extension.

Instead of checking extension only check MIME type also.